# Am I losing the 3NF of my table when I populate it with information

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

Created 2 tables which have a relation and are in 3NF.

**Table Employee:**

```
Emp_ID

Emp_First_Name

Emp_Last_Name

Emp_DOB
```

**Table Training:**

```
Training_ID

Train_Desc

Train_Date

Emp_ID (FK)
```

Even though they are in 3NF now, when I populate the training table with information and 2 people have the same training, wouldn't the Training table lose its 3NF? For example, as follows where the data is repeated.

[image]

Comment: What is `Training_ID`? Is it a reference to another table which contains tuples like (1001, 'Running'), (1002, 'Cycling') and so on?

Comment: you should have primary key on training table, but it should not be training ID, pk_trainingTr_id , your current Training ID should be fk_training_id & referencing a new table ms_training's pk_training_id.Let me know if more details are required.

Comment: @Carsten Training_ID is not a reference to another table. It is the primary key  for this table itself.

Comment: @AK47 Can you show me an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain,
First you should have master table for keeping training details as ,

```
Table ms_training:

pk_training_id int (Primary,identity)
training_date date
training_desc text
```

Then there should be transactional mapping table, which maps Training with Employee as,

```
Table tr_training:

pk_trainingTr_id (Primary key,identity)
fk_training_id(FK ref. ms_training)
Emp_ID (FK)
```

I hope I have able to explained properly, if not let me know.

Comment: I get your point. Just wondering if this is normal. Cos if I initially had like 4 tables having a relation, cos of this mapping it ends up becoming 8 tables.

Comment: I would suggest a `_header` table and a `_dtl` table but this would work.:)

Comment: @ChristianMark, can you please explain in brief?

Comment: @AK47, I am talking about the naming of your tables. instead of that, you can have `training_mstr` + `emp_mstr` then `training_hdr` and `training_dtl`.:) The `training_mstr` maintains the type of training(eg. running, lifting) then the `emp_mstr` maintains the employees. On the other hand, `training_hdr` maintains the schedule date and time then linked to the `training_dtl` that maintains the `training_id` and `emp_id`.

Comment: O , I got it, so now it depends on user requirement, if training schedule is Fixed & doesn't changes for any employee then MyWay, but if  schedule for particular training is different for different employee then YourWay. Thanks Mate for you time.